# System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken custom properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

My AuthServer is currently using the following code to generate a JwtSecurityToken:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);
```

The payload looks like this:

```
{
  "unique_name": "myUserName",
  "sub": "myUserName",
  "role": "API_User",
  "iss": "Automation",
  "aud": "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022",
  "exp": 1486056731,
  "nbf": 1483464731
}
```

I would like to add some custom fields/properties within the token payload, such as ProfilePicURL, so that the payload can look something like this:

```
{
  "unique_name": "myUserName",
  "sub": "myUserName",
  "role": "API_User",
  "iss": "Automation",
  "aud": "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022",
  "exp": 1486056731,
  "nbf": 1483464731,
  "profilePicture": "http://url/user.jpg"
}
```

How do I go about adding these custom properties and ensuring that the token contains them?

Comment: Add it to the Payload property, which is derived from `Dictionary<string, object>` ie `token.Payload["profilePicture"] = "http://url/user.jpg"`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`JwtSecurityToken` exposes a [`JwtPayload Payload { get; set;}`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityToken.cs#L220) property. [`JwtPayload`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtPayload.cs#L42) derives from `Dictionary<string, object>` so just add it to the payload...

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
token.Payload["profilePicture"] = "http://url/user.jpg"
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);
```

It is important that you use `WriteToken` to encode and sign the token, as simply getting the `RawData` property will not work (the token will not contain the custom claims).

Comment: Thank you!! Couldn't find this anywhere, didn't know it was a dictionary that you could edit!