# How to Validate JwtSecurityToken Custom Property

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, flutter, jwt

I am trying to add a custom property to my bearer token generated in a ASP.NET Core Web API (3.1). I currently have a well working login process that will dish out a bearer token to be used for authorizing request. I can see an issue where if someone hacks the username and pass they would then have a valid JWT and would have access to my api.

I am using this API for a mobile app (flutter) and want to add extra security. Using flutter/dart, I have access to a unique device id. I was hoping to include the device id in the bearer token and upon request extract the device id from the issued JWT and validate it from a DEVICE_ID request header value to confirm it is coming from the same device the JWT was initially requested from and generated for.

My first question is how can I do this? I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450141/system-identitymodel-tokens-jwtsecuritytoken-custom-properties) regarding Payload (token.Payload["custom prop"] = ...) but how can I extract this during authorization? Is there a better different way to accomplish this?

I was hoping to keep the validation contained so I can simply keep using the [Authorize] attribute above my api controller methods.

Here is my Startup ConfigureServices method

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),

                    };
                });
```

Here is where I generate the token:

```
 private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserModel user)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);
            token.Payload["DEVICE_ID"] = 1001; // Added here just as example of Payload
            var encodeToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return encodeToken;
        }
```

Here are some place methods that only need the [Authorize] attribute to automatically reject bad request:

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("Post")]
        public string Post()
        {
            var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            IList<Claim> claim = identity.Claims.ToList();
            var userName = claim[0].Value;
            return "Welcome To: " + userName;
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("GetValue")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
        }
```

I built the JWT Authorization for the API using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l56YLbAVAfo) tutorial online. Thanks for you help.

I just found [this (Microsoft: TokenValidationParameters.PropertyBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.propertybag?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_TokenValidationParameters_PropertyBag) and am trying to find some examples. In the doc it says "contains a collection of custom key/value pairs. This allows addition of parameters that could be used in custom token validation scenarios."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom claims using a payload like this:

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim("device_id", "smaple_id")); // custom property claim
};
```

Now here is a simple way instead of creating a custom token validator by using middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var deviceId = context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "device_id");
    var validationResult = DoSomeValidation(deviceId)
    if (validationResult == false)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized Device");
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

For cleaner code, use from middleware in an extension method.

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way to use your custom claims is [Claims-Based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1). In your Startup.cs you can put something like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("policy1", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CustomClaimName", "Accepted Value"));
});
```

And then in your controller, in the methods you want to protect you can add:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "policy1")]
```